# Find result of indexed set from 0 to n

Tags: notation, set-theory

For each $n \in \mathbb{N} $, let $A_n = \{0, 1, 2, 3,..., n\}$.
I don't know why $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i=\{0\}\ \cup\ \mathbb{N}$ while $\mathbb{N}$ has been from zero already.

Comment: $\{0\}\cup \{0,1,2,3,\dots\} = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ anyways, so even if you follow the convention that $\Bbb N$ has zero there should be no complaint beyond that the above may be slightly redundant.  Despite the redundancy, it avoids ambiguity.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some authors use $\mathbb{N}$ to mean $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, but some use it to mean $\{1,2,\dots\}$.